# Inf value is automatically forced after pattern matching

Tags: idris

Let's say we have an infinite list:

```
data InfList : Type -> Type where
     (::) : (value : elem) -> Inf (InfList elem) -> InfList elem
```

And we want to have finite number of its elements:

```
getPrefix : (count : Nat) -> InfList a -> List a
getPrefix Z _ = []
getPrefix (S k) (value :: xs) = value :: getPrefix k (?rest)
```

So, what is left:

```
  a : Type
  k : Nat
  value : a
  xs : InfList a
--------------------------------------
rest : InfList a
```

It turned out that after pattern matching `xs` become `InfList a` instead of `Inf (InfList a)`.

Is there a way to have `xs` delayed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be delayed anyway.

If you execute `:x getPrefix 10 one` with

`one : InfList Int
one = 1 :: one`

you get `1 :: getPrefix 9 (1 :: Delay one)`

I can't find it anymore in the documentation but idris seems to insert `Delay` automatically.

Comment: `getPrefix` is total, `[]` is a not an instance of `InfList`, take a closer look at how it's define - it cannot be empty

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, because I had immediately added it to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add `Delay` constructor manually. It's removed implicitly.

```
getPrefix : (count : Nat) -> InfList a -> List a
getPrefix Z _ = []
getPrefix (S k) (value :: Delay xs) = value :: getPrefix k xs
```